# show and hide footer and footer message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intel-xdk

I am trying to create an angular app using Intel XDK.Here when I run the index page we can see footer message.
What I need is the footer and footer message will show and hide every 5 seconds

index.html

```
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" style="background-color:#444444;">
            <div class="title">{{footer_message}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) ... [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular $interval or window.setInterval function

```
$interval(function() {
if($scope.showFooter)
{
$scope.showFooter =false;
}
else{$scope.showFooter =true;}
},5000);
```

Note: you have to inject $interval service in your controller

in your html :

```
<div ng-show="showFooter" class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" style="background-color:#444444;">
            <div class="title">{{footer_message}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: or `window.setInterval`..? What about `digest cycle` ?

Comment: I tried $interval()  first then it is working.And your code also working @RayonDabre

Comment: @Rayon Dabre  to be honest I am not aware about, how `code`digest cycle`code` works. Will definitely explore this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $interval() in controller page  and ng-show in index page

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a notification section in foorter message.so what you can do is bind the message variable in $scope.$watch service and check if that has some value and if that message has some value do null that instantly and in html section use a ng-show of that variable

```
$timeout(function () {
            $scope.footerMessage = null;


        }, 2000);
```

Comment: will you please explain more.or please fiddle?? @Rishabh Jain